# SQL Server Linked Server stays connected locally

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a linked server within XXXXX-02 database server so that it could communicate with the XXXXX-01 database server.

I do follow instructions, I do specify the remote server parameters, I do get a good connection, but no matter what I do, the linked server stays connected locally, only sees local tables, doesn't see the tables in the remote database.

I am at a stand still as no matter how explicitly I specify the remote server XXXXX-01, the connection properties of the linked server keep specifying the local server XXXXXX-02.

How can I change my script or settings to connect to the remote server

Here is the script to create linked server for XXXXXX-01

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [XXXXXXX-01]    Script Date: 11/5/2019 12:18:47 PM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @droplogins='droplogins'
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [XXXXXXX-01]    Script Date: 11/5/2019 12:18:48 PM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'XXXXXXX-01', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'XXXXXXX-01',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'XXXXXXX-01',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=N'ACCESS_SQL',@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'XXXXXXX-01', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Here is the screenshot with connection properties

[image]

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba. And James - or Mikhail - you should link the duplicate you posted on msdn - like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/james%20scourange/activity) to avoid wasting the efforts of others

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know you work together in these resources. What should I do? Delete this post, move it, or link it somehow?